# How do I save and reload the same PDF file each time instead of a new file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, pdf

I have two buttons Load PDF and Save PDF, when Load PDF is clicked it loads from server (NestJS server with postgreSQL that I have set up in the backend) and it embeds and previews the editable PDF. But I am unable to save the edited PDF when clicking on Save PDF button.

The editable PDF already has 6 input box, 2 dropdown bos and 4 radio buttons, and I want it such that when I change the values, it should save the edited/modfied values bacck to the server when clicking Save PDF.

I want it to Save back to the server with the Edited Content. How do I approach this.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { PDFDocument, rgb } from "pdf-lib"

const PDFViewer = () => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
  const url = `${domain}/example.pdf`
  const [pdfView, setPdfView] = useState(null)
  const [modifiedPdf, setModifiedPdf] = useState(null)

  const pdfRef = useRef(null)

  const loadPDF = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch PDF")
        return
      }

      const pdfBytes = await response.arrayBuffer()
      const pdfData = new Uint8Array(pdfBytes)
      setModifiedPdf(pdfBytes)
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData)

      pdfRef.current = pdfDoc

     
      const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

      const modifiedPdfBlob = new Blob([modifiedPdfBytes], {
        type: "application/pdf",
      })
      setPdfView(URL.createObjectURL(modifiedPdfBlob))
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading PDF:", error)
    }
  }

  const savePDF = async () => {
    if (!pdfRef.current) {
      return
    }

    const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfRef.current.save()

    const pdfDocUpdated = await PDFDocument.load(modifiedPdfBytes)

    const formData = await pdfDocUpdated.getForm()

    const formFields = formData.getFields()

    formFields.forEach((field) => {
      if (field.constructor.name === "PDFTextField") {
        console.log(field.getText())
      }
    })

    // const pdfData = new Uint8Array(modifiedPdfBytes)

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({ pdfData: [...modifiedPdfBytes] }), // Replace [] with the actual PDF data in Uint8Array format.
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("PDF saved successfully")
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to save PDF")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving PDF:", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadPDF}>Load PDF</button>
      <button onClick={savePDF}>Save PDF</button>
      <div>
        {pdfView && (
          <embed
            title="PDF Viewer"
            src={pdfView}
            width="100%"
            height="500px"
            style={{ border: "none" }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PDFViewer
```

Comment: Can you please add more details? What does the backend server look like? What currently happens when you click save?m What is in the response object?

Comment: @LucasHendren sure, It loads perfectly in the UI, but when I click on Save PDF it doesnt save the pdf with the modified changes back to the server. [https://imgur.com/a/FQceVPy] I've uploaded how the server controllers (nestjs) and the current preview. It is getting saved as per network, but not the edited PDF is getting saved. I want the edited pdf to be saved back to the server, and when click on Load PDF again, I want the edited pdf to be fetched.

Comment: @KJ that's the test case I am trying to solve, How can I automatically replace the pdf file after changes.